# Problems deploying a HttpModule in Asp.Net 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, httpmodule

I want to do UrlRewriting. in order to do that I have written a HttpModule that runs upon the `AuthorizeRequest` event in the ASP.NET Http Modules chain (before the request is processed by the HttpHandler).

### Context

I wrote an abstract class as a basic rewriter which implements the `IHttpModule` interface:

```
public abstract class BaseModuleRewriter : IHttpModule {
  public virtual void Init(HttpApplication app) {
    // WARNING! This does not work with Windows authentication!
    app.AuthorizeRequest += new ventHandler(this.BaseModuleRewriter_AuthorizeRequest);
  }
  public virtual void Dispose() { }
  protected virtual void BaseModuleRewriter_AuthorizeRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;
    this.Rewrite(app.Request.Path, app);
  }
  protected abstract void Rewrite(string requestedPath, HttpApplication app);
}
```

The real implementation of the module is the following class:

```
public class ModuleRewriter : BaseModuleRewriter {
  protected override void Rewrite(string requestedPath, System.Web.HttpApplication app) {
    // Just dummy, if the module works, I should never get to any page other than homepage
    UrlRewritingUtils.RewriteUrl(app.Context, "Default.aspx");
  }
}
```

In my web.config I have the following:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.web>
    <httpModules>
      <add type="ModuleRewriter" name="ModuleRewriter"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  ...
</configuration>
```

Actually this is a simple implementation of Url-Rewriting from an article posted in MSDN Megazine. I just made it simpler, but the approach is that one.

### The problem

It does not work! When I deploy the module like I told you and request a page, I can get to all my pages of my website, when, on the contrary, I should always be "redirected" to `Default.aspx`.

What to do?

### Additional info

First of all, one important information: My application pool is *Integrated Mode* targeting framework 4.0.

My web site is not compiled. I mean that I do not precompile my web site but I put all my code in the `App_Code` directory and let ASP.NET compile it when pages are requested. A direct consequence is that all my assemblies are put in the `%sysroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\...` directory.

I read some stuff where modules are deployed in the web.config by specifying the assemply as well, something like:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.web>
    <httpModules>
      <add type="ModuleRewriter, ModuleRewriterAssembly" name="ModuleRewriter"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  ...
</configuration>
```

But, being my stuff not precompiled, but entirely managed by Asp.Net, I cannot specify a different assembly. Is it needed to solve this problem? If so, what to do?

Thankyou

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on your appPool configuration (integrated vs classic mode), try adding

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add type="ModuleRewriter" name="ModuleRewriter"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Wow... seems working... Still having hands on it, I'll let you know, at least now I have some errors in the classes that I wrote! Finally I get a responsive application :)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the application pool resolved the issue. I changed it to integrated and it worked.